# Changing background image (adding new image path) with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my custom bg already. Also, I want to add a form field which will give to my visitors a choise to change it (they may add their custom BG url (any site) in to the form) + the result will store in the cookies. I know how to save any action in cookies, however I don't have any good example of how to change BG using form inputs.

Could any one help me please? I would apreciate any link on to a good example (which will support 1.9.1 version of Jquery) or your own example here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<input>
<button>done</button>
<div class="bg_img"></div>


$('button').click(function(){
 var bg_url = $('input').val();
    console.log(bg_url)
    $('.bg_img').attr('style','background-image:url('+bg_url+')');
});
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6BBy/)

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').attr('background-image', here is your cookie value where you store the image url);
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's a basic start. But I need a lil bit more information about how to make it work with form inputs properly.